# How to change state value by using it's instance in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

In my React.js project, I am trying to show error message when user select wrong item in the drop down box. Following is the code executed when user select wrong item in dropdown box. Current code is working well. But I think this is not recommend way to change state.(It seems changing "error" state directly.)

I hope to uncomment line 3 and want to comment line 2.(I think this is correct way as it is using instance of "error" state. I might be wrong, but I think so.) But it is not working well.

What is the reason? How to change error state by using it's instance? I don't want to change state directly.

```
  handleErrorChange = async (policy, error) => {
    const { errors } = this.state;                // I don't want this way.
    // const errors = { ...this.state.errors };   // I hope to use this way, but not working.
    if (policy) {
      errors[policy.id] = error;
      this.setState({ errors });
      // console.log(errors);
    }
    this.updateErrors();
  }
```

> ```
>   So finally, I want do like following.
> ```

```
  handleErrorChange = async (policy, error) => {
    // const { errors } = this.state;
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    if (policy) {
      errors[policy.id] = error;
      this.setState({ errors });
      // console.log(errors);
    }
    this.updateErrors();
  }
```

Comment: how do you say - `const errors = { ...this.state.errors }; ` this is not working ?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure why.

Comment: you came to that conclusion because of this line `console.log(errors)` ?

Comment: No. finally, when user select wrong item in the dropdown, error message is not showing.

Comment: how the state error is defined?

Comment: this.state = { errors: {} }  Like this.